# Discord bot forward message from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, discord, discord.js, xmlhttprequest

I have a chrome extension that uses console.log redirect into a div element when specific events happen. I have created a small Discord bot also (no functions or such, I just created and added it to my Discord channel)

Now instead of using console.log inside that div, I would rather want to send this information, to my bot and the bot should forward the message to a specific user.

Is that possible and if so, how?

Code for DC bot:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const slash = require('slash_commands.js');

const bot = new discord.Client({ intents: [discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

bot.login('xxx');

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot started');
});
```

So the bot is started and joined my Discord server. So maybe lets assume that this is the current situation:

Lets say my chrome extension is scanning for a website that contains prices. Instead of letting the chrome extension log the results to that div element, I would like to let the chrome extension send a command/message to my Discrod bot and then he will forward this inforamtion with a private message to a specific user.

Anyone had the same situation and could help me out how the code would have to like for this process? I was trying to figure it out myself for 4 days now.

Comment: Code for chrome extensions are visible to the client, exposing your discord API token is a massive risk. I don't recommend you connect a chrome extension with a Discord bot.

Comment: You could code a webhook into your chrome extension. Discord itself has a built in webhook receiver. Would probably be the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: You could work with [socket.io](https://socket.io/) as well by using emitters and event listeners. This one requires at least a server (could be a VPS or your own PC)

Comment: @ChristophBlüm note that discord webhooks can be deleted by the extension's users if they have the full webhook url, which makes using webhook equally useless as exposing the bot's discord API token.